# Hi, I have an error when validating my XML con DTD y Entity 'iacute' y Entity 'aacute'not defined

Tags: xml, dtd

I have an error when validating my XML:

```
Line position
2 Validation failed: no DTD found!
4 Entity 'iacute' not defined
22 Entity 'aacute' not defined
```

My XML is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset  xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
    <url>
        <loc>https://pruebasitemap.com</loc>
        <lastmod>May 24, 2021</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority> 0.8 </priority>
        <news:news>
            <news:publication>
                <news:name>La Silla Vacía</news:name>
                <news:language>es</news:language>
            </news:publication>
            <news:publication_date>May 24, 2021publication_date>
                <news:title>La Silla Vacía</news:title>
                <news:keywords></news:keywords>
        </news:news>
        <image:image>
            <image:loc>https://pruebasitemap.com/media/asas.jpg</image:loc>
        </image:image>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://pruebasitemap.com/2</loc>
        <lastmod>May 25, 2021</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority> 0.8 </priority>
        <news:news>
            <news:publication>
                <news:name>La Silla Vacía</news:name>
                <news:language>es</news:language>
            </news:publication>
            <news:publication_date>May 25, 2021</news:publication_date>
            <news:title>La Silla Vacía</news:title>
            <news:keywords></news:keywords>
        </news:news>
        <image:image>
            <image:loc>https://pruebasitemap.com/media/24.jpg</image:loc>
        </image:image>
    </url>
```

Comment: What are you validating it with? It is likely that the character `í` is being read as a named entity and that HTML 5 entity isn't recognized. Is the XML that you posted what is being parsed and validated, or is it being serialized before being sent to be validated? Post some code or the tools used with more context.

Comment: I suppose in the xml you will find these entities &iacute; and &aacute;  in html they get translated to í and á. In xml they are not allowed

Comment: Please  improve the tile, removing the greeting and details that follow later.